# jQuery find anchor tag with exact href

Tags: jquery, anchor, href

I'm using the following code to find anchor tags with a matching href URL. Currently it will return anchors linking to the requested URL, eg. `/images` AND any links to subfolders of that url, eg. `/images/recent`. I would like it to only return the first if I'm only asking for `/images`.

```
$menuChildren = $menuChildren.has('a[href^="'+relativeUrl+'"],a[href^="/'+relativeUrl+'"],a[href^="'+url+'"]');
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're using `^=`, the [Attribute Starts-With selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/=). As its name suggests, it matches attributes whose values *start with* the match string. Instead, use `=`, the [Attribute Equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) which requires an exact match:

```
$menuChildren = $menuChildren.has('a[href="'+url+'"]');
```

Comment: AH there's the explanation I needed. Thanks, will accept the answer in 3 minutes

Answer (score 15):

If you want to match the href exactly then use the `[href=...]` version

```
$menuChildren = $('a[href="' + relativeUrl + '"]');
```